# How to import RxSwift in Playground of xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, rx-swift

I am trying to import rxswift in xcode playground by this:

```
gem install cocoapods-playgrounds
```

and after that

```
pod playgrounds RxSwift
```

But it is not happening. How to do it?

Comment: You can add a playground to any project. If you know how to install the RxSwift pod then you are good...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. You should clone the [RxSwift repository](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) on your computer
2. Open `Rx.xcworkspace`
3. Build the `RxSwift-macOS` scheme
4. Open `Rx.playground` in the `Rx.xcworkspace` tree view and add a new page
5. `import RxSwift` in the new page.
6. Choose `View > Debug Area > Show Debug Area`

[image: steps 3 and 4]

[image: step 5]

Comment: i will try and let you give feedback on this

Comment: @JasonBourne I am attaching some images to guide you step by step

Answer (score 8):

it's super easy:

1. Create a new project, Xcode menu > File > New > Project… (Single
   View App)

   2. Close Xcode
   3. Initialize pods in the new project (pod init in terminal)
   4. Edit Podfile, add RxSwift, RxCocoa
   5. Install pods (pod install in terminal)
   6. Open RxSwiftProject.xcworkspace created by CocoaPods
   7. Build and run project using default scheme
   8. Add a new playground, Xcode menu > File > New > Playground…
   9. Select Add to: RxSwiftProject , to add it to the RxSwift workspace
   10. Save it in the workspace folder

[example code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANRY7.png)

Comment: Please do tag the question with appropriate technology. So that people working
For this question, please tag `swift`, `ios`.

Answer (score 3):

As @sas has hinted at, you can use [Arena](https://github.com/finestructure/Arena).

To be more specific:

---

One line to install Arena:

```
brew install finestructure/tap/arena
```

One line to create your RxSwift enabled Playground:

```
arena https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift
```

Results:

```
➡️  Package: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift @ from(5.1.1)
 Resolving package dependencies ...
 Libraries found: RxSwift, RxCocoa, RxRelay, RxBlocking, RxTest
 Building package dependencies ...
✅ Created project in folder 'Arena-Playground'
```

Done! Open `Arena-Playground` and find your Playground (probably called MyPlayground), code there. It may require a click on Product -> Build to get going the first time.

Answer (score 1):

No longer works in Xcode 9.1

`$ pod playgrounds RxSwift,RxCocoa`

gives

`Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Source/Playground with Platform Choice.xctemplate`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a playground with 3rd party SPM libraries with [Arena](https://github.com/finestructure/Arena):

```
arena https://github.com/finestructure/Gala
  resolving package dependencies
  libraries found: Gala
✅  created project in folder 'SPM-Playground'
```

That should work for RxSwift as well.

Answer (score 0):

@Jason, you need to run following commands:

`$ gem install cocoapods-playgrounds`

`$ pod playgrounds RxSwift,RxCocoa`

and it'll work. The second command opens a workspace with already added pods. Just remember to first build a target and then you can play with your new playground.

Comment: Does not work now. pod playgrounds RxSwift,RxCocoa. Why?

Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Source/Playground with Platform Choice.xctemplate...

Answer (score -1):

That so easy!

1. Create playground in your project(of course you need to need to add the dependency of RxSwift)
2. In Xcode project navigation, below the playground file, you will find a folder named source
3. Create this swift file in this folder:
   https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Rx.playground/Sources/SupportCode.swift
4. Then enjoy it!

   ```
   // example

   import RxSwift

   playgroundShouldContinueIndefinitely()

   example("of") {

   let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

   Observable.of("", "", "", "")
       .subscribe(onNext: { element in
           print(element)
       })
   }
   ```